# Appending data from a handler loaded after the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-on, jquery-append

I've made a site that displays a user's Facebook photos. The code below appends the photos to the div "facebook-images". This part works fine. The problem I have is that the images are being appended after the Javascript code below is loaded; so the handler "fb-image" is not created when the browser reads the click function code at the bottom, therefore it does not work.

I believe I need to use jQuery `on()`, but where? I've tried to put `on()` everywhere in the code below. I've tried to bind with append, I've tried live (which I know is deprecated but worth a shot). Nothing is working.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="target">
    
</div>
    
<div id="facebook-images">

</div>

<script>
    $.when(window.deferredes.fbLoaded, window.deferredes.fbLoggedIn).then(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + FB.getAccessToken(), function (data) {
            $.each(data.data, function (i, face) {
                $('#facebook-images').append("<div class='fb-image'><img src='" + face.source + "' ></div>");
            });
        });
    });

    $(".fb-image img").click(function () {
        $(".target").append("<h1>hi</h1>");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this is to add the click handlers AFTER the images are inserted into the page.

```
<script>
    $.when(window.deferredes.fbLoaded, window.deferredes.fbLoggedIn).then(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + FB.getAccessToken(), function (data) {
            $.each(data.data, function (i, face) {
                $('#facebook-images').append("<div class='fb-image'><img src='" + face.source + "' ></div>");
            });
            $(".fb-image img").click(function () {
                $(".target").append("<h1>hi</h1>");
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

---

You can also use delegated event handling if you want.  To do that, you set the event handler on a common parent that does exist at the time you run the event handling code with `.on()` and you use the delegated form of `.on()` by passing it a selector like this:

```
<script>
    $.when(window.deferredes.fbLoaded, window.deferredes.fbLoggedIn).then(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + FB.getAccessToken(), function (data) {
            $.each(data.data, function (i, face) {
                $('#facebook-images').append("<div class='fb-image'><img src='" + face.source + "' ></div>");
            });
        });
    });

    $("#facebook-images").on('click', ".fb-image img", function () {
        $(".target").append("<h1>hi</h1>");
    });
</script>
```

The delegated form of `.on()` works like this:

```
$(selector of static parent).on(event, selector that matches dynamic object, fn);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very accurate, detailed and fast answer! So fast I have to wait 2 mins before stack will let me click the correct answer. Also, thanks for the extra explanation and information. I didn't know about that but I'm definitely going to start using it. Cheers!